# How to Scan text file and output the following in java?

Tags: java, algorithm

For each student read from the file, output the following information:

```
Student Number (line number from the file, 1 to N)
Student Name (last name, a comma, and first name)
Student Athlete
Output Yes or No(Athlete Flag (Y = is an athlete, N = is not an athlete)
Eligibility-- Output either Yes or No --(Rule: If student is an athlete, their letter grade must be a “C” or higher to be eligible to play in the big game)
```

**this is how the text file looks:

Smith   Richard N   87  98  59  77  77  92  86

Johnson Daniel  Y   73  56  83  82  69  72  61

Williams    David   N   60  70  91  56  70  71  77

Jones   Carol   N   88  85  76  68  61  84  98

Brown   James   Y   67  91  62  73  74  83  94

Davis   Dorothy N   96  60  97  58  82  100 89

Miller  Jeff    N   80  74  74  68  64  90  87

Wilson  William N   61  83  96  59  67  68  60

Moore   Betty   N   65  59  93  86  72  80  73

Taylor  Helen   N   94  77  83  68  80  60  73

Anderson    Sandra  N   78  94  91  95  88  70  75

Each Row of the Text File Contains:

• Student Last Name

• Student First Name

• Athlete Flag (Y = is an athlete, N = is not an athlete)

• Grade on Quiz 1

• Grade on Quiz 2

• Grade on Quiz 3

• Grade on Quiz 4

• Grade on Quiz 5

• Grade on Test 1

• Grade on Test 2

This is i have written so far,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Assignment3 
{

    public static final void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        System.out.println("my name!");
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("students.txt"));

        String firstName = myScanner.next();
        String lastName = myScanner.next();
        String athlete=myScanner.next();
            int lineNumber =1;
             while (myScanner.hasNextLine())
             {
                 if(myScanner.hasNextLine())
                 {
                    myScanner.nextLine();

                 }
            System.out.println(lineNumber + " "+ lastName + ", "+ firstName +
            athlete);

                String firstName = myScanner.next();
                String lastName = myScanner.next();
                String athlete=myScanner.next();
                lineNumber++;  
            }
   }
}
```

I am really new to java. can anyone help please?

Comment: Your question essentially is: `"here are some broad requirements and here is some code"` and that's about it. These sort of questions are **very** hard to answer well and usually get closed. Please try to ask a much more specific and answerable question and you'll likely get a decent and specific answer.

Comment: Also, you're new here, and so please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, thereby getting better answers.

Comment: Its very use full if you can explain the output you want using an example. “Smith Richard N 87 98 59 77 77 92 86” what is the output for this record you want.

Comment: the output i want is at the top

Answer (score -1):

You can try for this code snippet, I didn’t get your question properly. But it's better to use BufferedReader instead of Scanner

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


  public class Assignment3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\students.txt"))) {

  String line;
  int lineNumber = 1;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);


    String[] words = line.split(" ");

    if (words.length <= 1) {
      continue;
    }

    String studentNumber = ""+ lineNumber++;
    String studentName = words[1]+","+words[0];
    String studentAthlete = words[2];


    boolean eligibility  = false;

    if(studentAthlete.equals("Y")){
        int totalMarks = 0;

       int subject = words.length-3;

        for (int i = 3; i < subject; i++) {
            totalMarks+= Integer.parseInt(words[i]);
        }

        int marksGrade = totalMarks/subject;

      //            now you can check the grade
        if(marksGrade<50){
            eligibility = true;
        }
    }

  }

} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

}
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your help, But this gives me this error output.  java.io.FileNotFoundException: students.txt (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
 at Assignment3.main(Assignment3.java:10)

Comment: for the FileNotFoundException: students.txt , give the file path to ------
new FileReader("C:\\students.txt") ---| [C:\\students.txt - change this path to your file]

Comment: By giving a spoon-fed answer, you are doing the original poster a disservice by robbing him of the opportunity of discovering the code for himself, and you encourage them to come here for whole solutions rather then to think for themselves first.

Comment: i am using a mac and eclipse. so i put the file in the default location. it was working with my project. i will try once more.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels sorry for that, I'm also thinking about that.

Comment: now its giving me this,                    Smith Richard N 87 98 59 77 77 92 86
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Assignment3.main(Assignment3.java:20)

Comment: mr. hovercraft i have gone through everything including javadoc and all other resources available for me. Thats why i asked here.

Comment: @MithunIslam: Come on now, you haven't shown us your best good faith code attempt to solve your issues, so you can say all you want about doing "everything" but until we see what you've tried, such statements are worthless.  If you don't do this, how will we know where you're stuck or what confuses you? Also your showing your effort gains much in terms of respect for you and your question, showing that you're willing to put in the effort and initiative to try to solve it yourself first.